# Is there a method to count the number of times a variable has been previously stated in a string in java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that replaces any vowel with a number, counting up from 0 whenever a vowel occurs, while using loops

what I have so far:

```
int num = 0;
for (int number = 0; number <= (insert method that returns the number of times num occured in the string here / number of vowels of any type previously seen in the string); number ++)
{
    num = number;
}
String word = "AEIOUaeiou87878alkjdaslwlejrlajflawjkflwj";
word = word.replaceAll("A", "" + num).replaceAll("E", "" + num)
           .replaceAll("I", "" + num).replaceAll("O", "" + num)
           .replaceAll("U", "" + num).replaceAll("a", "" + num)
           .replaceAll("e", "" + num).replaceAll("i", "" + num)
           .replaceAll("o", "" + num).replaceAll("u", "" + num);

System.out.println(word);
```

what is returned:

0123456789878780lkjd1slwl2jrl3jfl4wjkflwj

Does anybody know of a good way to make this work? Sorry if I'm not making much sense. I'm very new to coding.

Comment: I am unclear on your requirement - what is the number you want to insert? The number of any type of vowel seen previously? The number of `A`s seen previously etc?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What result you expect to be returned in place of `(insert method that returns the number of times num occured in the string here)` and why?

Comment: Only good debugging can help you out  here and ofcourse clear requirement.

Comment: The number of any type of vowel seen previously

Comment: I'd start by making some smaller use cases. This would allow me to make sure I am on track. Like abc -> 1bc (does it?), cab -> c2b (again, does it?).
What do you need to do to do this? (you are correct, a loop; but a loop over what? The whole string, a subset?) Then look at the [String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). What methods help you get where you want to go?

Comment: This sort of "Help me do my homework" generally are off-topic here. Either look at the smaller steps you need to do then ask questions about each of them (i.e. how do I loop over every element of a string, or how do I loop over each vowel in a string).

Comment: other cases: word = "abcdef"                                returned: 0bcd1f                           word = "Hello World"                    returned:  H0ll1 W2rld no idea how to format in comments, sorry

Comment: So how do you do that? If you were explaining the steps to a child, what would you say you needed to do?

Comment: @B.Horowitz The answer I have provided meets these criteria

Comment: @B.Horowitz - Personally I'd ignore the solutions below. Each of them IMO has concepts I don't think you teacher will be expecting you to use.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you replace all instances of one letter at once. You need to have a counter for the vowels starting a 0, then increment it whenever you find one, then build a string out of that counter and the other non-vowel characters.

For example,

```
public static void vowelReplacer(String word) {
    int vowelCount = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        char c = word.charAt(i);
        if ("aieou".contains(String.valueOf(Character.toLowerCase(c)))) {
            sb.append(vowelCount++);
        } else {
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

I/O

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    vowelReplacer("AEIOUaeiou87878alkjdaslwlejrlajflawjkflwj");
    // 01234567898787810lkjd11slwl12jrl13jfl14wjkflwj
}
```

Comment: Does doing the OPs homework for them really help the OP? I don't think it does.

Comment: @mlk - Does downvoting me make you feel better? I'm at least trying to help.

Comment: I disagree that you are helping. I'd say you are hindering the OP. The have a chance to learn right now.

Answer (score -1):

The most important step is to split the word into an Array. Then you can check your vowels step by step and replace the char with an int if its necessary. If not just leave the char as it is.

But if you have a match, dont forget to add one to `i` (`i++`)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String word = "AEIObUaeiou87878alkjdaslwlejrlajflawjkflwj";

        replaceVowel(word);
}

private static void replaceVowel(String word){
        String[] chars = word.split("");

        int i = 0;
        StringBuilder replacedWord = new StringBuilder();

        for (String oneChar : chars){
            if(check(oneChar)){
                replacedWord.append(String.valueOf(i));
                i++;
            }
            else{
                replacedWord.append(oneChar);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(replacedWord);
    }

    private static boolean check(String oneChar){
        oneChar = oneChar.toLowerCase();
        if(oneChar.equals("a")||oneChar.equals("b")){ // ...the rest of your vowels
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

For checking your vowels you only need lowercase because we are able to change the String to lowercase just for that check. So you have less writing.

Comment: using a regular expression matcher on a single `char` converted to a `String` can additionally reduce the complexity to read the if condition for vowel testing. i.e. `maybeVowel.matches("[aeiouAEIOU]")`. This also works *without* converting to lowercase